# How can i add list items to single product page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw17Q.png)
which block should I use to get a list as in the picture, a simple list block, I cannot dynamically change it in other products

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the standard wordpress builder and is the main thing you want them next to each other?

If so, you can create a list, then click "change block type or style" of the module and select column, adjust it to two and add another list next to it.

[image]

Comment: I need these sheets to be dynamic, for all my products they should have different content, when I put a simple sheet in the sample, the block is fixed and I cannot change it

Comment: I am creating a single product page template, but in it, I cannot add dynamic lists